Why is SARIMAX expensive to apply over high-frequency data in Python? (epochs=5mins) Any alternative models?
I’ve been experimenting with SARIMAX using statsmodels package to model time series data and understand seasonality and non-stationarity. My data is collected with a high frequency of 5-minute epochs, and I’m facing significant challenges:

Performance Issues: Applying SARIMAX with what I believe is the correct configuration (e.g., daily seasonality with 288 observations per day) is extremely slow. Sometimes, the process crashes due to memory or computational limits.

Suitability for High-Frequency Data: I suspect SARIMAX might not be the right choice for high-frequency datasets. Is this true? If so, why is SARIMAX particularly inefficient for such data?


Fixes or Alternatives:
Important Note: I am not interested in resampling or downsampling the data because it would cause a loss of valuable information that is critical for my analysis.
Questions:

Are there any techniques to optimize SARIMAX for high-frequency data without losing information?
Alternatively, are there better models specifically designed for high-frequency data that still allow me to understand time components like seasonality and trends?

I’m open to suggestions or insights from anyone who has tackled similar challenges with high-frequency data. Thanks in advance for your guidance!
I generated a reproducible example:
# !pip install pmdarima
# Import additional required libraries
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import pmdarima as pm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from statsmodels.tsa.statespace.sarimax import SARIMAX
from sklearn.metrics import mean_absolute_error, mean_squared_error
from datetime import datetime, timedelta


# Generate timestamps for 30 consecutive days with 5-minute intervals
start_time = datetime.now().replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)
timestamps = [start_time + timedelta(minutes=5 * i) for i in range(30 * 24 * 12)]  # 5-min epochs

# Generate 'avgcpu' data with seasonality
np.random.seed(42)  # For reproducibility
base_pattern = np.sin(np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, len(timestamps) // 30)) * 7.5 + 27.5
avgcpu = np.tile(base_pattern, 30) + np.random.normal(0, 2, len(timestamps))
avgcpu = np.clip(avgcpu, 20, 35)  # Normalize within the range [20, 35]

# Create a DataFrame
data = pd.DataFrame({
    "timestamp": timestamps,
    "avgcpu": avgcpu
}).sort_values("timestamp")


# Regenerate data and split into training and testing sets
test_size  = 2 * 24 * 12  # 2 days of data (288 * 2 observations)
train_data = data.iloc[:-test_size]
test_data  = data.iloc[-test_size:]

train_series = train_data["avgcpu"]
test_series  = test_data["avgcpu"]

Using the wrapper of SARIMAX and pm.auto_arima() unsuccessfully:

# Model 1: Using pm.auto_arima()
seasonal_period = 288  # Daily seasonality
model1 = pm.auto_arima(
    train_series,
    seasonal=True,
    m=seasonal_period,       # Seasonal period
    trace=True,              # Prints the model selection process
    error_action="ignore",   # Ignores non-converging models
    suppress_warnings=True,  # Suppresses warnings
    stepwise=True            # Stepwise model selection for faster computation
)

# Model 2: Using SARIMAX()
seasonal_period = 288  # Daily seasonality
model2 = SARIMAX(
    train_series,
    order=(1, 1, 1),                            # Simplified initial setup for ARIMA terms
    seasonal_order=(1, 1, 1, seasonal_period),  # Seasonal ARIMA terms
    enforce_stationarity=False,
    enforce_invertibility=False
)

# Fit SARIMAX model
sarimax_result = model2.fit(disp=False)

# Summary of models
print("Model 1 (auto_arima):")
print(model1.summary())

print("\nModel 2 (SARIMAX):")
print(sarimax_result.summary())

# Forecasting with both models for the test set period
forecast_model1, conf_int_model1 = model1.predict(n_periods=test_size, return_conf_int=True)
forecast_model2      = sarimax_result.get_forecast(steps=test_size)
forecast_mean_model2 = forecast_model2.predicted_mean
forecast_ci_model2   = forecast_model2.conf_int()

# Calculate metrics for both models
mae_model1 = mean_absolute_error(test_series, forecast_model1)
mse_model1 = mean_squared_error(test_series, forecast_model1)

mae_model2 = mean_absolute_error(test_series, forecast_mean_model2)
mse_model2 = mean_squared_error(test_series, forecast_mean_model2)


The SARIMAX method is already multithreaded. You should be able to see all your cores fire up in htop. So, if you don't want to downsample, no dice, basically. That's what you've got

so no chance ?! any trick or alternative model to understand seasonality and non-stationary time behavior?

You could try do a parametric study to find the optimal values for p and q so you can set the min and max values and stop it doing any scanning it might be doing

Argghh. I've forgotten the name of the wrapper I was using. My last comment won't make sense without it. Give me a few mins

How can I get this info? best\optimal P, Q? I just know my data is collected with epochs=5mins Even in the generated example I created seasonality and some overshoots but in the real dataset, I don't know if there is seasonality or periodic\cyclic behavior.  I just configured seasonal_period = 12*24 and passed seasonal_order=(1, 1, 1, seasonal_period) but about order=(1, 1, 1)  even though I checked available resources I could not come up with the best practice to set them in the best way for p, q. what is the best practice but again no chance to run my model but it takes so long

from pmdarima import auto_arima. That's the library I was using. You get to specify start_p and max_p etc. so you can limit the search space

I'm afraid autoregression is not the wrapper I'm looking for also here they offered using this class sm.tsa.AutoReg If I am not wrong that's the case for the out-of-sample forecast. here my depends on data split quality, I have test-set which counts in-sample forecast. I hope I'm not mistaken. in fact my test data is unseen and potentially I could use autoregression

It would be helpful if you looked at the documentation which shows that it takes params for SARIMAX. Elsewhere on the site - "The model internally wraps the statsmodels SARIMAX class"

I'm now experimenting pm.auto_arima() wrapper with minimal setup, i will come back to you if it is successful!

NameError: name 'train_data' is not defined. I do thank you for attempting to make it reproducible.

@J_H Sorry and thanks for your attention. I edited it so you can reproduce it and offer the solution

What does this example code purport to do? I thought I was just being patient, but after time reported real 56m7.519s
user 72m36.448s
sys 1m7.890s
and seeing no output I gave up and hit CTRL/C. There's a lot of magic numbers in there, which interact with one another. I tried e.g. reducing 288 to 28 in the hopes of getting an answer 10x faster, but found there were a bunch of other details that would also need to be adjusted.

@J_H Thanks for your effort. same here I used 2 different wrappers of SARIMAX() and pm.auto_arima() unsuccessfully. Please see my 2nd edit. even though I simplified generating data with less complexity to be close to the minimal example but the issue is wrappers of expensive and they run for so long time. I remember I did reduce the but it did not work .

seasonal_period = 8 works :) for both models see this but the fact is it should be 288 and the good thing is  pm.auto_arima() wrapper shows the best numbers\configuration if the runs finish seeing here for seasonal_period = 28 it crashes due to RAM in Google Colab medium
